# Facebook Login Using UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, facebook

My app was rejected by Apple because "Login via Facebook" opens the Safari app, because I am using UIWebView for Facebook login, which is working fine. I am getting the access token as well.

The problem is I also need user information like user ID, email ID, user name etc. because I need to save it on my server.

How do I get the logged-in user's info when I have the access token?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the FB iOS documentation?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/

There is an API called FBRequest which can retrieve various information or the Graph API can be used to obtain stuff.
How to integrate FB login with an iOS app is fully documented with example projects.